# If I use "localhost", is it guaranteed that the client is local? (considering I can edit the system hosts file)

Tags: java, security, dns

If I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2205111/287316) solution:

```
new ServerSocket(9090, 0, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"))
```

...and the user changes it's system hosts file to access my website as "localhost", will this fail to prevent access from non-local client?

Comment: Yes, the user could probably override localhost to that it's no longer 127.0.0.1

Comment: Why not `InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress()` ?  (J2SE 7+)

Comment: Whatever IP address is returned by InetAddress.getByName it is either a "local" address of the box, so either `127.0.0.1` typically or any other IP address of the box, or any other random outside IP address in which case the `ServerSocket` will fail as you can not start to listen on an IP address not tied to the box.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I believe the intent was to prohibit listening on any externally accessible interface.

Comment: @Alnitak yes sure, but if the client control the box, even if you listen on 127.0.0.1, the client can just put a firewall rule to redirect all incoming trafic on any external IP and given port to 127.0.0.1. So if user controls the box, the application does not have a lot of protections, and using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` gives basically the same level of guarantees.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yes, that's true :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(in response to the bounty call)*

As always in computer security, *guarantee* depens on attacker *capabilities*.

1. The attacker is lame and knows nothing. Then yes, `localhost` guarantees the locality of the client.
2. The attacker has login access to the system and can run SSH to the outer world. Then no guarantees - SSH can forward internal ports through tunnels:

```
ssh -R *:8080:localhost:9090 some.external.server
```

Executing this command on the box with your java server will result in establishing a tunnel. All requests addressed to `some.external.server:8080` will be delivered to `localhost:9090` of the target box.

VPS nowdays costs almost nothing, so the attacker can easily rent such external box and use it as the proxy between your localhost and the whole world.

3. You may try to protect your server by filtering out all requests where `Host` header is not `localhost`. It could be easily countermeasured by including a header-rewriting proxy, such as nginx, to the forwarding chain.

## Summary

As you can see, *guarantee* means that users in the target box must be severely limited: no forwarding software. It implies denying users access to system utilities like `ssh` or installing and/or running them with user privileges. This is highly unlikely unless the box is a set-top box without any user login or software reconfiguration.

## Localhost address

The first comment to the question suggests a trick with `localhost` name resolution:

> the user could probably override localhost to that it's no longer 127.0.0.1

The idea is to place a record to `/etc/hosts` or `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` that binds `localhost` name to another IP address.

If your box has an Ethernet connection with, say, address 1.2.3.4, then the line

```
1.2.3.4 localhost
```

**might** cause change of `localhost` address. If this happens, then the line

```
new ServerSocket(9090, 0, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"))
```

will bind the port 9090 on the *external* network interface, that is accessible from the outside of the box.

I tried this on Ubuntu 18.04, and it worked. I successfully connected to the app running on `localhost` in the box on the other side of Pasific.

**BUT**

Once upon a time MS Windows developers hardcoded `localhost` to be `127.0.0.1`. [Here is the Medium post about that](https://medium.com/software-developer/change-what-localhost-resolves-to-in-windows-for-testing-ie-edge-on-parallels-or-virtualbox-vm-60a002849d94).

I checked with my Windows 10 box. Confirmed: `localhost` resolves to `127.0.0.1`. The test program

```
package org.example;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TryLocalhost {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("localhost: " + InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
    }
}
```

produces

```
localhost: localhost/127.0.0.1
```

while `hosts` file tried to bind `localhost` to the link-local address

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
192.168.0.198 localhost
```

The comment is original, from Microsoft.

Comment: So, changing the hosts file in my Windows is not enough if I don't have login access to the system?

Comment: @TomBrito, [since Windows Vista or Windows 8](https://medium.com/software-developer/change-what-localhost-resolves-to-in-windows-for-testing-ie-edge-on-parallels-or-virtualbox-vm-60a002849d94) `localhost` in Windows is hardcoded to be `127.0.0.1`. Today I edited `hosts` in my Windows 10, but `InetAddress.getByName("localhost")` kept resolving to `127.0.0.1`. Still on Linux it works - tried on Ubuntu 18.04. 
So, on modern Windows machines you can be sure `localhost == 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @TomBrito added localhost story to the answer.

Comment: actually, I just though about it now, you would need to change the hosts file on the server machine right? Changing it on your local Ubuntu machine cannot trick the server into resolving 'localhost' to what's on your machine... right?

Comment: @TomBrito, yes, hosts file must be modified at the box where `InetAddress.getByName("localhost")` is executed. That is at the server. Fooling hosts on the client side has no effect. Note, changing hosts file requires login access and admin privileges.