# loopback ip using socketserver on java

Tags: java, server, serversocket

I have been tying to create a server on loop-back device using `ServerSocket`.

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT, 0,  InetAddress.getByName(null));
```

The host to reach the server is provided as `ip6-localhost/::1`  however it results in error: `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`

any pointer on how to access local server using `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Did you try some of the answers and comments in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205073/how-to-create-java-socket-that-is-localhost-only

ie- trying to pass in localhost or 127.0.0.1 instead?

Comment: @Howard_Roark thank you. replacing `null` with `localhost` worked.

Comment: Ok great -- I'll move my comment to an Answer to "close the loop" or whatever phrase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the answers and comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205073/how-to-create-java-socket-that-is-localhost-only) address this problem.  ie- passing in `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead

```
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9090, 0, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"))
```