# How to create Java Socket object serving on localhost only?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I ask this question again here ( [How to create Java socket that is localhost only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205073/how-to-create-java-socket-that-is-localhost-only) ) 'cause all before mentioned methods (simply to say to create one ServerSocket by 3 parameters method) can not solve my problem.

I am working in one big intranet in which, every time when I open one browser, I need enter my proxy account and password to access internet. This is why I hope to test my socket program on localhost.

Occasionally my Client side can connect the Server side, but usually I have to wait for a long time before she coming out. I suppose, it should be related with some of proxy/firewall.

[image]

Although I look over all following resources and believe all of them are well worth reading, but I still can not get my issues out.

http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html

[How to determine an incoming connection is from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542424/how-to-determine-an-incoming-connection-is-from-local-machine)

My Server Side Code

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Myserver {
    private int serverPort = 8000;
    private ServerSocket serverSock = null;

    public Myserver(int serverPort) {
        this.serverPort = serverPort;

        try {
            /*SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), serverPort);
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.bind(socketAddress);
            serverSocket.accept();*/
            serverSock = new ServerSocket(serverPort, 0, InetAddress.getByName(null));

        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
     public void handleConnection(InputStream sockInput, OutputStream sockOutput) {
        while(true) {
            byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
            int bytes_read = 0;
            try {
                // This call to read() will wait forever, until the
                // program on the other side either sends some data,
                // or closes the socket.
                bytes_read = sockInput.read(buf, 0, buf.length);

                // If the socket is closed, sockInput.read() will return -1.
                if(bytes_read < 0) {
                    System.err.println("Tried to read from socket, read() returned < 0,  Closing socket.");
                    return;
                }
                System.err.println("Received "+bytes_read
                                   +" bytes, sending them back to client, data="
                                   +(new String(buf, 0, bytes_read)));
                sockOutput.write(buf, 0, bytes_read);
                // This call to flush() is optional - we're saying go
                // ahead and send the data now instead of buffering
                // it.
                sockOutput.flush();
               // sockOutput.close();

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.err.println("Exception reading from/writing to socket, e="+e);
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                return;
            }

        }

    }

    public void waitForConnections() {
        Socket sock = null;
        InputStream sockInput = null;
        OutputStream sockOutput = null;
        while (true) {
            try {
                // This method call, accept(), blocks and waits
                // (forever if necessary) until some other program
                // opens a socket connection to our server.  When some
                // other program opens a connection to our server,
                // accept() creates a new socket to represent that
                // connection and returns.
                sock = serverSock.accept();
                System.err.println("Have accepted new socket.");

                // From this point on, no new socket connections can
                // be made to our server until we call accept() again.

                sockInput = sock.getInputStream();
                sockOutput = sock.getOutputStream();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }

            // Do something with the socket - read bytes from the
            // socket and write them back to the socket until the
            // other side closes the connection.
            handleConnection(sockInput, sockOutput);

            // Now we close the socket.
            try {
                System.err.println("Closing socket.");
                sock.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.err.println("Exception while closing socket.");
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }

            System.err.println("Finished with socket, waiting for next connection.");
        }
    }

}
```

My Client Side Code

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyClient {
    private String serverHostname = null;
    private int serverPort =0;
    private byte[] data = null;
    private Socket sock = null;
    private InputStream sockInput = null;
    private OutputStream sockOutput = null;

    public MyClient(String serverHostname, int serverPort, byte[] data){
        this.serverHostname =  serverHostname;
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void sendSomeMessages(int iterations) {
        System.err.println("Opening connection to "+serverHostname+" port "+serverPort);
        try {
            sock = new Socket(serverHostname, serverPort);
            sockInput = sock.getInputStream();
            sockOutput = sock.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            return;
        }

        System.err.println("About to start reading/writing to/from socket.");

        byte[] buf = new byte[data.length];
        int bytes_read = 0;
        for(int loopi = 1; loopi <= iterations; loopi++) {
            try {
                sockOutput.write(data, 0, data.length); 
                bytes_read = sockInput.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
            if(bytes_read < data.length) {
                System.err.println("run: Sent "+data.length+" bytes, server should have sent them back, read "+bytes_read+" bytes, not the same number of bytes.");
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Sent "+bytes_read+" bytes to server and received them back again, msg = "+(new String(data)));
            }

            // Sleep for a bit so the action doesn't happen to fast - this is purely for reasons of demonstration, and not required technically.
            try { Thread.sleep(50);} catch (Exception e) {}; 
        }
        System.err.println("Done reading/writing to/from socket, closing socket.");

        try {
            sock.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Exception closing socket.");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        System.err.println("Exiting.");
    }
}
```

My Test Code

```
import java.net.*;

public class Mytest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hostname = "localhost";
        int port = 8000;

        try {
            InetAddress add = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

             System.out.println( add);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
                {
                     e.printStackTrace(); 
                }


        byte[] data = "my program".getBytes();

        MyClient client = new MyClient(hostname, port, data);
        client.sendSomeMessages(10);   

       Myserver server = new Myserver(port);
        server.waitForConnections();
    }

}
```

I try telnet, but I can't connect it at all

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that the test code runs **both** the client and the server. In `Mytest.main()`, the main thread does the following:

1. Creates a client (I would have thought that this step would fail)
2. Tries to send some messsages (but no `ServerSocket` has been started)
3. The server is created
4. The server waits forever, blocking the main thread on `accept()`

As a starter to get your code working. Create two test classes `TestServer` and `TestClient`, both of these must have `main()` methods. Launch `TestServer` first in it's own Java process. Next launch `TestClient` in separate Java process. This *should* work!

After you've got everything working, you should introduce some concurrency into your server. The way that it's currently written it can only serve a single client at a time. Create new threads to manage new sockets returned from `accept()`.

Good luck!