# Java test if socket is localhost

Tags: java, sockets

I am wondering how I can detect if a socket is coming from localhost, that means the sockets is open on pc1 and connects to a server on pc1, i tried the address but i hav'nt got it to work, is there a call like isLocalhost() or somthing like that where i can test for a localhost socket?

Tried code:

```
    if(socket.getInetAddress().getHostName().equalsIgnoreCase("127.0.0.1")) {

    }
```

but sadly that didn't work, I also tried with the ipv6 but also that didn't trigger the if statement.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You are getting `HostName` and comparing it with the IP address of `127.0.0.1`. You can use `getHostAddress()` instead of `getHostName()`. However `getHostAddress()` is not going to return `127.0.0.1` in all networks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine an incoming connection is from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542424/how-to-determine-an-incoming-connection-is-from-local-machine)

Answer (score 1):

Its socket.getInetAddress().isLoopbackAddress()

Comment: A client can connect to a local server without using a loopback address